# Command to delete temp files using cmd

Tags: windows-7

Can anyone help me in removing temp files using cmd, i have used all these commands

```
rd /s /q %temp%
mkdir %temp%
rd /s /q c:\windows\temp\
mkdir c:\windows\temp\
```

Reuslts what i'm getting is " temp already exist"

Comment: It cannot delete the temp folders, especially in the windows folder because it is in use. you will want to delete all files in the folder and skip anything in use, instead of deleting the folder itself and recreating it.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave c:\windows\temp intact and delete the files within. Do not remove the folder and recreate because there are busy files in there. Not all the files can be deleted.

So just delete what you can and leave the rest behind.

This is entirely normal for Windows.

Answer (score -2):

This is the one I use, it will delete any file on the C: drive with .tmp file extension, never had any issues using it.

```
cd\
erase *.tmp /s
```

Comment: I find this a very dangarous command. I would never use this. One typo can erase more than one wants and it will not delete everything that is temp.

Comment: There are many commands that way, I guess it pays to be careful. :-)

Comment: Careful while using this..use at own risk